# How do make sure longer "spans" go to a new line in a table having fixed width?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, fixed-width

I have a table whose width is fixed. Its 'tbody' is generated from an ajax response.

I have an example of what I'm trying to do at http://jsfiddle.net/p5LL7/7/  
Click on the button to simulate an ajax response.You will see that the second word i.e. "panther" breaks on to the next line.  How do I make sure:

1. Spans which contain smaller words are displayed on the same line(like the second row of the table) BUT
2. Spans which contain longer words are displayed on the next line ?

Comment: inline-block on your spans is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the spans a css property of `display: inline-block;` and then they should just wrap automatically.

Lose the break-word property also.

Answer (score 1):

```
.mngAppSpan{
  float:left;
  ..
  .
}
```